# error in final step of veins tutorial

Tags: omnet++

When I run the command to start SUMO,it prints Listening on port 9999 and starts directly to print also :

```
Handling connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 63825  
Got  Traci message of length 1347375952  
Got Traci command of length 31  
Got Traci command 0x2f  
Aborting on error:Expected CMD-FILE_SEND(0x75),but got 0x2f  
Closing connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 63825
```

Connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 63826
Handling connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 63826
Got........

And so one

Instead of waiting for the simulation to start.

And it continues to print the same error message even if I start the simulation  or I close the simulation.
So the same error message continues to be printed on the command terminal until I close it.

What is wrong? And someone knows how can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you please provide some more insights on your setup, what Veins and SUMO version you use. What command you use to initiate the `sumo-launchd.py`, what operating system are you running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system seems to run another program that tries to connect to TCP port 9999. Independent of whether you are running this program knowingly or [if it is malware](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=9999), either shutting down the conflicting program or changing the sumo-launchd.py port number will help. See the [sumo-launchd.py documentation](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/sumo-launchd/) for how to change its port number.